# How do I add weights to my moving average function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can calculate the simple moving average using the code:

```
def movingaverage (values, window):
    s = pd.Series(values)
    sma = s.rolling(window).mean()
    return sma
```

But now I want to add weights into my function so it can calculate weighted moving average, I tried this:

```
def movingaverage (values, window):
    s = pd.Series(values)
    weights = np.arange(1,window)
    sma = s.rolling(window).mean().apply(lambda values: np.dot(values, weights)/weights.sum())
    return sma
```

But the results are like this:

```
0                                    [nan, nan]
1                                    [nan, nan]
2      [27.555555555555557, 55.111111111111114]
3        [26.88888888888889, 53.77777777777778]
4      [25.444444444444443, 50.888888888888886]
                         ...                   
360     [28.777777777777775, 57.55555555555555]
361      [28.11111111111111, 56.22222222222222]
362                                [27.0, 54.0]
363    [25.666666666666668, 51.333333333333336]
364     [25.777777777777775, 51.55555555555555]
```

What part I was wrong? How should I add weights into my function? Thank you!

Comment: What is the input, expected output and actual output? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
def movingaverage(values, window):
    s = pd.Series(values)
    weights = np.arange(1,window+1)
    sma = s.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.sum(x*weights)/weights.sum(), raw=True)
    return sma
```